# Почему JSDoc не видит локальные комментарии?

Tags: javascript, документация, jsdoc

В коде ниже [генератор документации jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc) не видит локальные комментарии к функциям и переменным.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    /**
   * Конвертирует Rem в Пиксели
   * @param   {Number} rem Сколько rem сконвертировать в пиксели
   * @returns {Number} Кол-во сконвертированных пикселей
   */
  function convertRemToPixels(rem) {
    return rem * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
  }
});
```

То есть при компиляции чистое окно:
[image]

Когда же обёртывающей функции нет, JSDoc видит и можешь прочесть эти комментарии:

```js
/**
 * Конвертирует Rem в Пиксели
 * @param   {Number} rem Сколько rem сконвертировать в пиксели
 * @returns {Number} Кол-во сконвертированных пикселей
 */
function convertRemToPixels(rem) {
  return rem * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
}

console.log(convertRemToPixels(2))
```

[image]

jsdoc.json:

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": "./src/js/main.js",
    "excludePattern": "(node_modules/|docs|dist)"
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./docs/",
    "readme": "./readme/readme.md"
  }
}
```

Как исправить такое поведение JSDoc? Если не знаете ответа, посоветуйте генератор документации каким пользуетесь вы. Спасибо!